Full width UICollectionViewCells overlap during interface orientation rotations causing ugly animation
Preface
I'll preface this illustrating the issue visually. Here's a video of the issue: upon rotating the interface, the UICollectionViewCells overlap, generating an unpleasant animation that for sure can't be used in production.
The code
The code was executed on iPhone 6S (NN0W2TU/A A1688) with iOS 15.8.2. I could reproduce the issue on iPhone 15 Pro with iOS 17 on simulator as well.
Please note that my scene delegate's func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) { } sets window?.rootViewController = ViewController().
SelfConfiguringCell.swift:
import UIKit

protocol SelfConfiguringCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    static var reuseIdentifier: String { get }
    
    func configure(with image: String)
}

ISVImageScrollView.swift:
import UIKit

public class ISVImageScrollView: UIScrollView, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
  
  // MARK: - Public
  
  public var imageView: UIImageView? {
    didSet {
      oldValue?.removeGestureRecognizer(self.tap)
      oldValue?.removeFromSuperview()
      if let imageView = self.imageView {
        self.initialImageFrame = .null
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(self.tap)
        self.addSubview(imageView)
      }
    }
  }
  
  // MARK: - Initialization
  
  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.configure()
  }
  
  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    self.configure()
  }
  
  deinit {
    self.stopObservingBoundsChange()
  }
  
  // MARK: - UIScrollView
  
  public override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.setupInitialImageFrame()
  }
  
  public override var contentOffset: CGPoint {
    didSet {
      let contentSize = self.contentSize
      let scrollViewSize = self.bounds.size
      var newContentOffset = contentOffset
      
      if contentSize.width < scrollViewSize.width {
        newContentOffset.x = (contentSize.width - scrollViewSize.width) * 0.5
      }
      
      if contentSize.height < scrollViewSize.height {
        newContentOffset.y = (contentSize.height - scrollViewSize.height) * 0.5
      }
      
      super.contentOffset = newContentOffset
    }
  }
  
  // MARK: - UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
  
  public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return otherGestureRecognizer === self.panGestureRecognizer
  }
  
  // MARK: - Private: Tap to Zoom
  
  private lazy var tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = {
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapToZoom(_:)))
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    tap.delegate = self
    return tap
  }()
  
  @IBAction private func tapToZoom(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    guard sender.state == .ended else { return }
    if self.zoomScale > self.minimumZoomScale {
      self.setZoomScale(self.minimumZoomScale, animated: true)
    } else {
      guard let imageView = self.imageView else { return }
      let tapLocation = sender.location(in: imageView)
      let zoomRectWidth = imageView.frame.size.width / self.maximumZoomScale;
      let zoomRectHeight = imageView.frame.size.height / self.maximumZoomScale;
      let zoomRectX = tapLocation.x - zoomRectWidth * 0.5;
      let zoomRectY = tapLocation.y - zoomRectHeight * 0.5;
      let zoomRect = CGRect(
        x: zoomRectX,
        y: zoomRectY,
        width: zoomRectWidth,
        height: zoomRectHeight)
      self.zoom(to: zoomRect, animated: true)
    }
  }

  // MARK: - Private: Geometry
  
  private var initialImageFrame: CGRect = .null
  
  private var imageAspectRatio: CGFloat {
    guard let image = self.imageView?.image else { return 1 }
    return image.size.width / image.size.height
  }
  
  private func configure() {
    self.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    self.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    self.startObservingBoundsChange()
  }
  
  private func rectSize(for aspectRatio: CGFloat, thatFits size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    let containerWidth = size.width
    let containerHeight = size.height
    var resultWidth: CGFloat = 0
    var resultHeight: CGFloat = 0
    
    if aspectRatio <= 0 || containerHeight <= 0 {
      return size
    }
    
    if containerWidth / containerHeight >= aspectRatio {
      resultHeight = containerHeight
      resultWidth = containerHeight * aspectRatio
    } else {
      resultWidth = containerWidth
      resultHeight = containerWidth / aspectRatio
    }
    
    return CGSize(width: resultWidth, height: resultHeight)
  }
  
  private func scaleImageForTransition(from oldBounds: CGRect, to newBounds: CGRect) {
    guard let imageView = self.imageView else { return}
    
    let oldContentOffset = CGPoint(x: oldBounds.origin.x, y: oldBounds.origin.y)
    let oldSize = oldBounds.size
    let newSize = newBounds.size
    var containedImageSizeOld = self.rectSize(for: self.imageAspectRatio, thatFits: oldSize)
    let containedImageSizeNew = self.rectSize(for: self.imageAspectRatio, thatFits: newSize)
    
    if containedImageSizeOld.height <= 0 {
      containedImageSizeOld = containedImageSizeNew
    }
    
    let orientationRatio = containedImageSizeNew.height / containedImageSizeOld.height
    let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: orientationRatio, y: orientationRatio)
    self.imageView?.frame = imageView.frame.applying(transform)
    self.contentSize = imageView.frame.size;
    
    var xOffset = (oldContentOffset.x + oldSize.width * 0.5) * orientationRatio - newSize.width * 0.5
    var yOffset = (oldContentOffset.y + oldSize.height * 0.5) * orientationRatio - newSize.height * 0.5
    
    xOffset -= max(xOffset + newSize.width - self.contentSize.width, 0)
    yOffset -= max(yOffset + newSize.height - self.contentSize.height, 0)
    xOffset -= min(xOffset, 0)
    yOffset -= min(yOffset, 0)
    
    self.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: xOffset, y: yOffset)
  }
  
  private func setupInitialImageFrame() {
    guard self.imageView != nil, self.initialImageFrame == .null else { return }
    let imageViewSize = self.rectSize(for: self.imageAspectRatio, thatFits: self.bounds.size)
    self.initialImageFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageViewSize.width, height: imageViewSize.height)
    self.imageView?.frame = self.initialImageFrame
    self.contentSize = self.initialImageFrame.size
  }
  
  // MARK: - Private: KVO
  
  private var boundsObserver: NSKeyValueObservation?
  
  private func startObservingBoundsChange() {
    self.boundsObserver = self.observe(
      \.self.bounds,
      options: [.old, .new],
      changeHandler: { [weak self] (object, change) in
        if let oldRect = change.oldValue,
          let newRect = change.newValue,
          oldRect.size != newRect.size {
          self?.scaleImageForTransition(from: oldRect, to: newRect)
        }
    })
  }
  
  private func stopObservingBoundsChange() {
    self.boundsObserver?.invalidate()
    self.boundsObserver = nil
  }
}

CarouselCell.swift:
import UIKit
import SnapKit

class CarouselCell: UICollectionViewCell, SelfConfiguringCell, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    static var reuseIdentifier: String = "carousel.cell"
    
    internal var image: String = "placeholder" {
        didSet {
            self.imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: image))
            self.scrollView.imageView = self.imageView
        }
    }
    
    fileprivate let scrollView: ISVImageScrollView = {
        let scrollView = ISVImageScrollView()
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 30.0
        scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0
        scrollView.contentOffset = .zero
        scrollView.bouncesZoom = true
        

        return scrollView
    }()
    
    fileprivate var imageView: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")!
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)

        return imageView
    }()
    
    public func setImage(_ image: String) {
        self.image = image
    }
    
    func configure(with image: String) {
        self.setImage(image)
        
        self.scrollView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.left.top.right.bottom.equalTo(contentView)
        }
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        scrollView.delegate = self

        scrollView.imageView = self.imageView
        contentView.addSubview(scrollView)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("Cannot init from storyboard")
    }
    
    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return self.imageView
    }
}

ViewController:
import UIKit

class ViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    private var currentPage: IndexPath? = nil
    
    private let images = ["police", "shutters", "depot", "cakes", "sign"]
    
    init() {        
        let compositionalLayout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { sectionIndex, environment in
            
            let absoluteW = environment.container.effectiveContentSize.width
            let absoluteH = environment.container.effectiveContentSize.height
            
            // Handle landscape
            if absoluteW > absoluteH {
                print("landscape")
                let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
                    widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
                    heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1)
                )
                
                let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
                
                let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
                    widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
                    heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1)
                )
                
                let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
                
                let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
                return section
            } else {
                // Handle portrait
                
                print("portrait")
                let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
                    widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                    heightDimension: .absolute(absoluteW * 9.0/16.0)
                )
                
                let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
                
                let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
                    widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                    heightDimension: .absolute(absoluteW * 9.0/16.0)
                )
                
                let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
                
                let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
                return section
            }
        }

        let config = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration()
        config.interSectionSpacing = 0
        config.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        
        compositionalLayout.configuration = config
        
        super.init(collectionViewLayout: compositionalLayout)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
        
        // Register cell for reuse
        collectionView.register(CarouselCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CarouselCell.reuseIdentifier)
    }
    
    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.images.count
    }
    
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let reusableCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CarouselCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? CarouselCell else {
            fatalError()
        }
        
        let index : Int = (indexPath.section * self.images.count) + indexPath.row
        
        reusableCell.configure(with: self.images[index])
        
        return reusableCell
    }

}

Notes
I found a similar unanswered question here. I'm sure something can be done about it because if I switch to SwiftUI with a TabView, that according to this, is using UICollectionView under the hood, I'm not getting that ugly animation anymore. Though I can't switch to SwiftUI to use TabView because on interface rotation it loses the page index (well known bug, see here), which probably is even trickier to workaround.
EDIT:
Updated dead video exhibit of the issue.

Your video link is not available. Try explaining what you're trying to do, and what's not working as desired.

It's not entirely clear what you're running into, but try adding this to your ViewController class:
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    let theLastIndex = Int(self.collectionView.contentOffset.x / self.collectionView.bounds.width)
    coordinator.animate(
        alongsideTransition: { [unowned self] _ in
            self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: theLastIndex, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
        },
        completion: { [unowned self] _ in
            // if we want to do something after the size transition
        }
    )
}

See if that fixes the problem.

Edit
What appears to be happening (an inherent issue with collection view):

When we rotate the device and change the cell width, UIKit is "holding onto" the .contentOffset as it's re-lays-out the views:

and we get some funky animations.
Since you're not committed to using a collection view, I'm going to suggest a completely different strategy...
Add a UIPageViewController as a child VC, add its view as a subview, and update the size of that subview when needed.
Too much code to post here - but if you add me as a collaborator on your GitHub repo (my GitHub ID is the same as here - "DonMag"), I can push a branch with a working example.

Thanks for your time. Unfortunately that didn't fix. This is what happens after adding your code to ViewController.

@Bafforasta - hmmm... wonder if something's missing from your code, or I may have made a slight change elsewhere... can you post a [mre] somewhere like GitHub?

I uploaded the project to a github repo here. There's other stuff as well and dependencies to install via CocoaPods, but the relevant files are that in my post.

I removed the unnecessary code from the repo.

@Bafforasta - are you committed to using UICollectionView with compositional layout?

Not really, I was actually tempted to go the hyperoslo/lightbox way with a UIScrollView and simulated paging. But if UICollectionView did the trick it'd have saved me some headache.

@Bafforasta - see the Edit to my answer.

I'll gladly add you as a collaborator. I suspected it had to be something like that. Thank you so much for all your effort!

@Bafforasta - I just pushed to that repo. Added a "DonMag" Branch. You should be able to switch to my Branch and run it (before you start digging into the code).

Thank you for your help, I tried running it and it does its job greatly. Tomorrow I'll inspect the code a little and think I'll reward you with the bounty.
